# Get image name (and other file properties) onclick in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

In [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) after upload all images, how i can get file name when clicking one of them?

http://runnable.com/me/VN-nEtJXQqlk07H4 
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the contents of the src attribute?

Comment: I need just name. (alt attribute)

Comment: I do not have time to implement it, but can you not add click functionality to your dropped file with dropzone's addedfile event? http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

Comment: Yes i can do it but i want get file name after all uploads done

Answer (score 4):

You can access the HTML of the file preview in any of the events with `file.previewElement` and bind "onclick" event listener.

**This works for me, in a similar situation:**

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function() {
        this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
            console.log(file); // will send to console all available props
            file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
               alert(file.name);
            });
        });
  }
};
```

*I was displaying files from the server, recommended from documentation `addedfile` event didn't fire, that's why I used `thumbnail` instead (fires when thumbnail has been generated).*

**Result (after clicking on filename):**
[image: alert after clicking on file name]

**Tips from [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#tips)**:

> To access the preview html of a file, you can access
>   file.previewElement. For example:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    myDropzone.removeFile(file);
  });
});
```

**Other available `file` properties:**

[image: console.log(file)]

Comment: Thank you! I use this approach to perform an action (view larger image) when clicked